# Get Delayed output of a variable

Tags: python, loops, variables, output

hey I have a Loop That is always running That keeps changing a variable Called X like this
And It keeps running And keeps changing. And I want to get the previous output of the variable. How Can I do this?

```
while True:
  X = X+10
  X = X*5
  
  print(X)
```

Comment: Moving `print` statement before changing `X`?

Comment: There's no magic.  If you want the old value, then you need to save the old value somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to save just the value of X from the previous loop, or do you want to save _all_ previous values?

Comment: From the previous loop not all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in an array and select the last element of the array

Comment: To improve your answer and clear your point/idea it is better to provide code (or pseudo code) in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you're looking for when you say previous output of variable. I'd suggest you to also read on loops if you've just started with python. Here's a [source](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/)

```py
while True:
    print(x) #this will print value X after each iteration 
    x= x+10
    x= x*5
```

Answer (score 0):

The psuedo code:
arr1 = []

infinte loop:
x= x+10
x= x*5
append x to array
print  arr1 index current time looping minus one